# Sorting structures from files

Tags: c, file, sorting, struct

I recently got an assignment to sort members in a struct by last name and if they are the same to sort by first name. What i have so far only reads their name and age from the file but I am not properly grapsing how I would be able to sort it. So far I gathered the data from the file but im at a loss from there. I followed a code I saw but i didnt get a proper grasping of the process so i reverted back to step one.

```
struct  Members{
    int id;
    char fname[50];
    char lname[50];
    int age;
}bio; 

int main(){
    int i=0;
    FILE *fptr;
    file = fopen("Members Bio.txt", "r");
    while ( fscanf(file, "%d%s%s%d", &bio[i].id,bio[i].fname,bio[i].lname,&bio[i].age) != EOF) 
    {
        printf("%d %s %s %d %d\n", bio[i].id,bio[i].fname, bio[i].lname, bio[i].age);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Can anyone help me out on this one?

Comment: "So far I gathered the data from the file..." No you didn't. Not with that code. The code has several bugs. It can't even compile. For instance, `bio` is used as an array but `bio` isn't an array.

Comment: Tip: `!= EOF` --> `!= 4`

Comment: Tip: For sorting arrays, `qsort` is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code goes something like this for your case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct  Members{
    int id;
    char fname[50];
    char lname[50];
    int age;
};

typedef int (*compare_func)(void*, void*);

int struct_cmp(void* s1, void* s2)
{
    int l_result = strcmp(((struct Members*) s1)->lname, \
            ((struct Members*) s2)->lname);

    if (l_result < 0)
        return 1;
    else if (l_result > 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return (strcmp(((struct Members*) s1)->fname, \
                ((struct Members*) s2)->fname) < 0 ? 1 : 0);
}

void sort(void* arr,long ele_size,long start,long end,compare_func compare)
{
    // Generic Recursive Quick Sort Algorithm

    if (start < end)
    {
        /* Partitioning index */

        void* x = arr+end*ele_size;
        long i = (start - 1);
        void* tmp=malloc(ele_size);

        for (long j = start; j <= end - 1; j++)
        {
            if ((*compare)(arr+j*ele_size,x))
            {
                i++;

                // Swap is done by copying memory areas

                memcpy(tmp,arr+i*ele_size,ele_size);
                memcpy(arr+i*ele_size,arr+j*ele_size,ele_size);
                memcpy(arr+j*ele_size,tmp,ele_size);
            }
        }

        memcpy(tmp,arr+(i+1)*ele_size,ele_size);
        memcpy(arr+(i+1)*ele_size,arr+end*ele_size,ele_size);
        memcpy(arr+end*ele_size,tmp,ele_size);

        i= (i + 1);

        sort(arr,ele_size,start, i - 1,compare);
        sort(arr,ele_size,i + 1, end,compare);
    }
}

int main()
{
    FILE* fp;
    int bio_max = 3;
    struct Members bio[bio_max];    // Define bio to be large enough.

    /* Open FILE and setup bio matrix */

    /* For testing */

    bio[0].id = 0;
    strcpy(bio[0].fname, "");
    strcpy(bio[0].lname, "Apple");
    bio[0].age = 0;

    bio[1].id = 1;
    strcpy(bio[1].fname, "");
    strcpy(bio[1].lname, "Cat");
    bio[1].age = 1;

    bio[2].id = 2;
    strcpy(bio[2].fname, "");
    strcpy(bio[2].lname, "Bat");
    bio[2].age = 2;

    /* Sort the structure */

    sort(bio, sizeof(struct Members), 0, bio_max - 1, struct_cmp);

    /* Print the sorted structure */

    for (int i = 0; i < bio_max; i++) {
        printf("%d %s %s %d\n", bio[i].id, bio[i].fname, \
                bio[i].lname, bio[i].age);
    }

}
```

Output

```
0  Apple 0
2  Bat 2
1  Cat 1
```

If the strings are not sorting in the way you want, you can redefine the `struct_cmp` function. Code is self explanatory, the base logic in the code is pass an array and swap elements using `memcpy` functions. You cant use simple assignment operator if you want to be generic, so that is why the element size is explicitly passed.

### Edit

The code was not handling the condition, if lname are same. I missed it thanks for @4386427 for pointing this out.

Comment: 1) Use `qsort` ? 2) This code only sorts on `lname`

Comment: @4386427 1) Honestly speaking till today I was not aware of libc qsort function. If known i wouldn't be taking pain of writing a sort function on my own, from today i will use that :) 2) Yes thats the question requirement, if question requirement is different then different compare function must be used

Comment: @4386427 oops i missed the second condition ! if strcmp is zero then other check is required.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define bio to be an array. And google sort algorithms please. Also recommend you google how to use libc function `qsort`.

Comment: Well, what you write is correct but it's not really an answer that helps OP.